What is this font called and how to study it
What is this font called , I thought that in German it's called "Gotisch" but a Google search proved me wrong.
Also, whats a good way to learn how to read it?


Well, the historic record indicates that it was used by the Goths! ;-)

Googling "German font" yields the answer: Fraktur.

It's called "Fraktur" in German, or more general, "gebrochene Druckschrift", while in English it's often called Gothic print.
Wikipedia has letter tables that you can use to learn it. The most peculiar features to know about it are the 'long s' (ſ) that looks like an f on first look, the forms of k and z, and a number of capital letters that are quite different from Antiqua (the usual latin letters we use today).

It's also called Fraktur in English. A related term is blackletter, which includes similar typefaces. It's not a specifically German typeface by the way, but it's associated with German because it was still used for German text until the middle of the 20th century. It's still used occasionally for certain mathematical symbols, in particular for Lie algebras. For reading it, it really helps to know German so you can fill in the hard to read letters from context.

Wow, while I can read it I think I simply recognize words and sentences. Looking at the actual letters: The "U" from "Ueber" and the "A" from "Aufnahme" are practically identical! Even the capital "P" has only a minor difference (because, I suppose, the decorative swirls common to all letters take up most of the space).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: I actually think this is a typesetting error, the typesetter got confused and set an A instead of a U in "Ueber". The U is normally clearly wider at the top than the A, you can see that in the smaller print.

@RDBury: Fraktur was the dominant typeface in German-speaking countries (although its use was waning) until it was finally forbidden by the Nazis. Lookup the "Bormann-Erlaß" from 1941, see for instance: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiqua-Fraktur-Streit In view of that it is tragically funny that Neonazis like to use the oh-so-Gerrmann Fraktur typeface. (On the other hand: being able to think straight perhaps prevents becoming a Nazi anyway.)

@HalvarF Ah, that is possible!

@HalvarF: The "U" just looks narrower because of the diacriticals: it is an "Ü", not an "U". The headline reads: "Über die Aufnahme von Proselyten in das Judenthum". If you look at the picture zoomed in you will see that the rightmost strokes of "U" and "A" are different.

@HalvarF You are correct. There is a U in col. 2's 10th line.

@bakunin No; umlauted capitals are not used here; rather, the plain capital vowel followed by e are used, e.g. Ueber.

@RosieF: you are right, my bad, but the point stands: there is a difference between "U" and "A" in the rightmost stroke (in the upper part).

@bakunin Looks like a smudge to me. Also, the whole headline is repeated in the table of contents ("Inhalt" ), and there you can also see that there's quite a difference between A and U. On the other hand, the announcement at the very top about the subscriptions has the words "Abonnement" and "Unterbrechung", and now I'm kind of unsure again about which way the typo went in the headline. Could also be both U, depending on the font.

@HalvarF: The headline and the text (the TOC) are different fonts. Both are Fraktur but not the same Fraktur.

@bakunin Yes, I have of course seen that.

@HalvarF It’s clear from the announcement at the top that the typoed headline says, “Ueber die Uusnahme”. The A’s in the two instances of Abonnement in the announcement have quite a different shape (no vertical right stroke, and it doesn’t contain the ‘’-like stroke on the left). The font in the announcement looks like the same as in the article header, just bolder.

@JanusBahsJacquet: "Aufnahme, ", bzw. fehlerhaft "Uufnahme", jedenfalls nicht "Ausnahme" respektive "Uusnahme". Das s hat im Gegensatz zum f keinen Querstrich.

@userunknown Yes, Uufnahme, absolutely! I was so focused on the first letter I totally forgot to check the rest of the word.

Here's the Fraktur - Wikpedia Entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur
I think the main letters that cause some confusion are:

k -> looks like "f" (+ extra line)

s -> looks like "f" (no cross)

x -> looks like "r" (+ extra line)

y -> looks like "g" or "n"

g -> looks like "y"

z -> looks like "3"

A -> looks like "U" (sometimes)

P -> looks like "B" (sometimes)

I -> Looks like "J" (sometimes)


This will all depend on the which specific fraktur font you're looking at.

The other answers explain the key differences to modern fonts, so I just wanted to focus on the 'how do I learn to read it' part.
The key question is whether you can read modern German in a modern font?
If so, the easiest way to learn to read Fraktur is just to practice reading it because you can fill in most differences to modern fonts from context. Note also that the texts you are reading were written at least around 100 years ago, so the language and spelling can be somewhat archaic as well. But in summary I would say any native German speaker can read Fraktur and with a little practice it would be almost as fast as a modern font.
If you can't read modern German, this is way harder and I would suggest some kind of automated translation to English. Possibly multiple steps are needed, first a text recognition software (that knows German and Fraktur fonts) and then a translation software. Where the translation doesn't make sense you probably need a careful word for word study.

Since nearly 10% of our population is analphabetic, not any german speaker can read it. If you account for people with IQ below average, I would expect that the majority can't read it. And I don't understand how an automated translation to English and text recognition software may help in learning to read it.

@userunknown: You're just making stuff up. (i) "Germany has a 99% literacy rate for people over the age of 15" (according to CountryReports). (ii) "Analphabetic" means you don't even know the alphabet; so there are even fewer analphabetes than illiterates.

@TonyK https://www.ardalpha.de/wissen/analphabeten-alphabetisierung-lesen-schreiben-lernen-100.html schreibt:
"Aber auch in Deutschland gibt es viele Erwachsene ohne ausreichende Lese- und Schreibfertigkeiten: 6,2 Millionen Deutsch sprechende Menschen im Alter zwischen 18 und 64 Jahren sind Analphabeten - jeder achte in dieser Altersgruppe. Das geht aus der Studie "LEO 2018 - Leben mit geringer Literalität" der Universität Hamburg hervor."

@userunknown: That is a (deliberate?) falsehood from ARD alpha. The referenced study LEO 2018 - Leben mit geringer Literalität says: "...dass es in Deutschland rund 6,2 Millionen Erwachsene gibt, deren Lese- und Schreibkompetenzen für eine volle berufliche, gesellschaftliche und politische Teilhabe nicht ausreichen". This is not what "illiterate" or "analphabetic" mean.

@TonyK: this is not a "falsehood", it is just saying it in different words. If something is "not ausreichen(d)" it doesn't really matter how much not ausreichend it is. If - as an example - you die from starving it won't matter if the starvation results from too little food or no food at all. Dead is dead.

@bakunin Calling people with low literacy analphabets is a falsehood because contrary to your starvation example there are degrees of literacy. People with low literacy may be unable to fully write or read a complex text like the example in the question. People who are analphabets are not able to read on the package whether they hold a milk or an orange juice container. There is a world of difference between the two.

@quarague: Yes, there are degrees of literacy, but, and I quote: "deren [...] Kompetenzen [...] nicht ausreichen" means "nicht ausreichend". "volle berufliche, gesellschaftliche und politische Teilhabe" is not reached when one is able to read above text, but at a significantly lower level - which is still not reached.

@bakunin That was precisely my point, their literacy is not sufficient for full participation. That in no way implies that they are complete analphabets. If your reading skills are similar to those of a second grader they are not sufficient for full participation but you are nowhere close to an analphabet.

@quarague: and my (and obviously userunknowns) point is: being unable to read well enough for your own good is being unable to read well enough for your own good - does it really matter "how much" they do not know how to read? A long time ago I learned ancient Greek in school. I can read Greek newspapers and - more or less - know how the spoken text sounds although I don't understand it (I never learned modern Greek). Is that really any "better" than a Chinese newspaper, which I can't read at all? Not getting it is not getting it, period.

But @bakunin, user unknown started out by asserting that “nearly 10% of our population is analphabetic” [emphasis added]. And that does not mean the same thing as “nearly 10% of our population is unable to read well.”

@PaulTanenbaum: so, let me correct/rephrase what user unknown said: not nearly 10% of our population is analphabetic but nearly 10% of our population is factually analphabetic. Do you really think this makes all the difference in this (sad enough) fact?

I am not qualified to hold an opinion on that question, @bakunin. There is a battle of statistics in this thread. As for me, my only point was that user unknown’s original statement is stronger than the one you later defended to quarague.

If someone speaks multiple languages, one of them German, but their German is not good enough to follow a political debate, that does not make them "analphabetic". It doesn't make them "factually analphabetic" either. There is a huuuuuge gap between "not being able to fully participate in social and political life" and analphabetic.
